# How to make the switch work?

Tags: java, android

There is a lot programmatically created buttons, that's 2 of them:

```
Button agafon_1 = new Button(this);agafon_1.setText(R.string.txt_agafon_1);llPreViewList.addView(agafon_1, lParams);
Button agafon_2 = new Button(this);agafon_2.setText(R.string.txt_agafon_2);llPreViewList.addView(agafon_2, lParams);
```

There OnClickListener and it has a switch. What do I need to insert in place of the question marks to make the switch work?

```
switch (???) {
case ???:
//
break;
case ???:
//
break;
}
```

The file R.java not even mention the id buttons which makes it impossible to use v.getId()...

Comment: Switch works for int (up to JDK6) and for String (JDK7) I believe. I suggest the int option, just assign int to every button and than switch through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same `OnClickListener` for every Button set a different id for every `Button` with `Button.setId(int)`  and the use `v.getId()` for your `switch`, where `v` is the argument of `onClick()`. Otherwise you can create a different `OnClickListener` for every button

Answer (score 0):

You class should implement `OnClickListener`

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Then

```
     Button agafon_1 = new Button(this)
     agafon_1.setId(yourbuttonid); 
     agafon_1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
       switch(v.getId())
       {
        case buttonid1 : // id must match
        break;
        case buttonid2 :
        break;
        ... 

       }
  }
```